# SQL select query by hours

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

Help me to write a select query to get record counts by hour. I want all the 24 hours displayed in the output even if there is no record available in the table for a particular hour.

for example

```
Date       Hour Record count
----------------------------
2013/03/01 00 - 100
2013/03/01 01 - 0 (No records available in the table)
2013/03/01 02 - 200
2013/03/01 03 - 300
2013/03/01 04 - 0 (No records available in the table)
```

...it goes on... till 23 hours...

This is the query I am using currently...

```
SELECT VALUE.DATETIME, COUNT(*) as TOTALPOBYCREATEDTIMEANDDATE 
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(TIMECOL)) <= 4 
                       THEN DATECOL CONCAT '00'
                  WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(TIMECOL)) = 5 
                       THEN DATECOL CONCAT '0' CONCAT SUBSTR(TRIM(TIMECOL),1,1) 
                  ELSE DATECOL CONCAT SUBSTR(TRIM(TIMECOL),1,2) END as DATETIME 
      FROM ORDLIB/ORDERTABLE 
      WHERE DATECOL LIKE '201303%') VALUE 
GROUP BY VALUE.DATETIME 
ORDER BY VALUE.DATETIME
```

Comment: Please provide your attempts at this so far. SO isn't here for people to just write code for you.

Comment: .... are your date/time columns actually character types?  It'd be best if you could turn them into actual date/time/timestamp types.  Regardless, could we get sample starting data?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an 'hours' table with a row for each hour.  Then do a LEFT JOIN to get all the hours represented.  Hours rows without records will be returned as NULL but you can COALESCE those if you prefer zero instead of null.